# trace location path on Google Map

Tags: mysql, google-maps, trace

I am developing an application in which  i draw a path of the last 5 locations(longitude & latitude) saved in an existing MySQL database on Google Map API.
Does anyone know the code please? thank in advance

Comment: Have you seen the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) documentation on [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines)?

Comment: Yeah I just did , thanks

Answer (score 1):

To draw the the line from the data returned in your MySql server you would just use a simple polyline: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

I found the best way to do this is to make an array var a = []; and push each lat, long from the server into the array.

Example:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
];
```

Then you can add it to the map or remove it from the map pretty easily

```
flightPath.setMap(map);
flightPath.setMap(null);
```